# Why does this prove that $a^n$ goes towards infinity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

My textbook is using some kind of strange technique using binomials to prove a point. Since they're using this techniques on several other occasions I need to understand what they are doing and why.

They begin by trying to prove that $a^x$ goes towards infinity when x goes towards infinity given that $a>1$. I have no earthly idea why this would need på be proven, but fine.

In order to prove this they first write that:

$$a^x=(1+p)^x \ge (1+p)^n $$

Where $n$ is the "whole-number-component" of $x$ or $[x]$

This can then be rewritten as:

$$ (1+p)^n=1+np+\binom{n}{2}+...+ p^n \ge np $$

I'll just accept that this checks out somehow. They next claim that this is definite proof that:

$$ a^x \ge np \ge (x-1)p $$

And that this in turns proves that $a^x$ goes towards infinity as long as $x \ge 1$

Here they officially lost me. Where does $(x-1)p$ even come from and how exactly would this prove $a^x$ going towards infinity?

Comment: The condition $x\ge 1$ can be omitted because we let $x$ tend to $\infty$. Note that $p$ is a positive real number because of $a>1$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition $n \leq x<n+1$ In particular, $n >x-1$. Hence, $np \ge (x-1)p $

$(x-1)p \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$, so $a^{x} \to \infty$ as $x \to \infty$